# Create tab-section similar to browser tabs in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on web-application developing tab-section similar to chrome-browser tab using reactjs.

My requirements are -
Tab-section similar to chrome-browser tab.
On selecting a feature in side-navbar, a tab has to pop in the tab-section.
On selecting a new feature in side-navbar, a new tab has to pop in the tab-section.
Closing of tab.

I have gone through react-draggable-tabs, but it does'nt have on selecting a feature a tab has to pop instead it shows entire tab.

Please help me out in it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.